# Blazor webassembly unable to put breakpoints

Tags: debugging, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly

The goal is to be able to debug the client part of my blazor application. For this, in the sources accessible in the browser, I need to put breakpoints. The problem is that the sources are not apparent in the browser.

When I start my project in debug, I go to the localhost with the port of the sslPort property of the lauchSettings.json file

1. Then with Shift+Alt+D I will retrieve the instruction to execute.
2. I have the new window that appears, if I do Shift+Alt+D again I have the source tab that appears but there is no file:// folder as mentioned [Debug ASP.NET Core Blazor WebAssembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/debug?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio) in the Debug in the browser section

For information, at first I could not access part 2 because I had the following error:
[websocket disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wJpw.png)

I managed to make progress by following this post:
https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26824#issuecomment-707825522

Has anyone encountered this error or have a clue?

Comment: No one has an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem, but I don't know the real cause.
Below I explain my problem in case it can help someone, because I spent a lot of time to understand.

My post was intended but to help me put breakpoints in my client side code of a Blazor WASM application.
While setting the breakpoints in Visual Studio, I had an error telling me that the source code was not found, which is why I wanted to try the method through the browser sources.

I decided to go back to my original problem in Visual Studio.
I noticed that I can only debug projects that are stored in the source/repos directory in the  folder. I tried in a VM, in it I can store my projects anywhere on disk.
On my pc, I found that Visual Studio is installed on disk C, but it also has settings on another disk, my 2 disk organization seems to be the cause. Because if I create or move the projects anywhere on the other disk, it works every time, if I take this project and put it on disk C, it doesn't work anymore. Unfortunately I didn't have the problem for a test project I created while trying to figure it out, so I see it can possibly be fixed.

To recap, if you have 2 disks with Visual Studio present on both, try testing on the other disk.